# Как в данном коде сделать так чтобы выводился и второй параметр

Tags: java, массивы, enum, параметры

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TaxiStation ts= TaxiStation.valueOf(TaxiStation.class,"Volvo".toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(ts+ " : ordinal -> " + ts.ordinal());
    ts.setFreeCabs(3);
    ts.setSpeedLimit(200);
    TaxiStation[] stations = TaxiStation.values();
    for (TaxiStation element : stations){
        System.out.println(element);
    }

  }
  public enum TaxiStation {
    MERCEDES(10,200),TOYOTA(7,150),VOLVO(0,0);
    private int freeCabs;
    private int speedLimit;

    TaxiStation(int cabs,int speed){
        speedLimit=speed;
        freeCabs=cabs;
    }
    public int getSpeedLimit(){
        return speedLimit;
    }
    public void setSpeedLimit(int speed){
        speedLimit=speed;
    }
    public int getFreeCabs(){
        return freeCabs;
    }
    public void setFreeCabs(int cabs){
        freeCabs=cabs;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s : free cabs = %d",name(),freeCabs);
    }
  }
}
```

Изначально выводиться только параметр freeCabs, нужно сделать так чтобы выводился и параметр speedLimit

Answer (score 1):

```
return String.format("%s : free cabs = %d, speed limit = %d", name(), freeCabs, speedLimit);
```